# Load test of web application with high number of users (50,000 Users)

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing

We have a MVC Web application and we wants to do the load testing for this application with 50k users. Currently we are doing the distributed testing from non-GUI mode using J Meter. We are able to simulate 7k users using 10 different machines (Master-slave configuration).

However to achieve 50k users we need a large number of machine that is cumbersome process. Is there any free tool available to achieve this.

Comment: If you have 50K users in your web app then one server should be fine for this. Remember that 50K total users is not the same as 50K concurrent users (that would be like Facebook or Google levels of traffic).

Comment: @halfer yeah that would be fine, we don't want 50k concurrent users.

Comment: OK, with that in mind, do you still need multiple machines? If you are doing load testing I expect you'll want real machines rather than VMs, or would VMs be acceptable for your purposes? Either way, you could try a devops tool like Ansible or Puppet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

50k users != 50k concurrent requests.

1. Users don't hammer application non-stop, they need some time to "think" between operations
2. Users have to wait till next page loads

So

- if user "thinks" for 10 seconds between operations and page load time is 2 seconds each user will issue 5 requests per minute
- 50k users will send 250k requests per minute
- 250k requests per minute is ~4150 requests per second

The numbers might be different depending on nature of your application, however if you can simulate 7k concurrent requests you should be able to convert them into 50k concurrent users.

Take a look at [JMeter Timers](https://blazemeter.com/blog/comprehensive-guide-using-jmeter-timers), there are various implementations which allow to:

- set virtual user think time, like [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) or [Uniform Random Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Uniform_Random_Timer)
- set desired throughput in requests per minute - [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)
- pause threads until specified amount is reached and releasing them at the same moment to create a "spike" - [Synchronizing Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)

Answer (score -1):

I hope others have answered your point on the concurrent users. If you still need to test them using cloud solution (agents), Here is the link for 20,000 minutes of free web load testing through VSTS Azure Datacenter - https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vs/alm/test/performance-testing/getting-started/getting-started-with-performance-testing

You can buy additional minutes online and distribute your tests in mutliple VM's across different regions.